# How to cancel an ActionResult method that is currently running from another ActionResult method?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax-request

In my MVC website has show button for process data. This button call to the ActionResult method "ProcessData".

```
public ActionResult ProcessData()
    {
        bool isComplete = false;
        string errMessage = "";
        try
        {
            //Calculate something that take long time.


            isComplete = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            errMessage = e.Message;
        }


        return Json(new { IsComplete = isComplete, ErrorMessage = errMessage });
    }
```

And the second button for cancel process. This button call to the ActionResult method "CancelProcessData".

```
public ActionResult CancelProcessData()
    {
        bool isCancelComplete = false;
        string errMessage = "";
        try
        {
            //Cancel Process Data


            isCancelComplete = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            errMessage = e.Message;
        }


        return Json(new { IsCancelComplete = isCancelComplete , ErrorMessage = errMessage });
    }
```

1. When user clicked at the process button, the data is processing and takes a long time.
2. I want the user to be able to cancel a process by click at the cancel button.

**How to cancel an ActionResult method that is currently running from another ActionResult method? Please introduce me.**

P.S. Sorry for bad english skill.

**Edit 1: this is code in ProcessData.cshtml**

```
<script>
    function ProcessData() {
        var actionUrl = '@Url.Action("ProcessData", "Home")';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: actionUrl,
            contentType: "application/Json",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.IsComplete) {
                    var reUrl = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
                    window.location = reUrl;
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    }

    function CancelProcessData() {
        var actionUrl = '@Url.Action("CancelProcessData", "Home")';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: actionUrl,
            contentType: "application/Json",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.IsComplete) {
                    alert("Cancel Complete");
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<button onclick="ProcessData();">Process Data</button>
<button onclick="CancelProcessData();">Cancel Process Data</button>
```

**End edit 1**

**Edit 2:After I search for long time. I find a solution for cancel process. this code is shown**

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> ProcessData()
    {
        bool isComplete = false;
        bool isCancel = false;
        string errMessage = ""; 
        try
        {
            await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => {
                for (int i = 0;i< Int32.MaxValue; i++)
                {
                    if (HttpContext.Response.ClientDisconnectedToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        isCancel = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });

            isComplete = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            errMessage = e.Message;
        }


        return Json(new { IsComplete = isComplete, ErrorMessage = errMessage, IsCancel = isCancel });
    }
```

this below is script function

```
<script>
    var ajaxProcessDatarequest;
    function ProcessData() {
        var actionUrl = '@Url.Action("ProcessData", "Home")';
        ajaxProcessDatarequest = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: actionUrl,
            contentType: "application/Json",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.IsComplete) {
                    if (!result.IsCancel) {
                        var reUrl = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
                        window.location = reUrl;
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    }

    function CancelProcessData() {
        ajaxProcessDatarequest.abort();
    }
</script>
```

**End edit 2**

Comment: can you post the HTML part of Cancel and Show buttons. You are calling using ajax ?

Comment: You cant (they are 2 separate requests)

Comment: `ProcessData` & `CancelProcessData` take different requests (they're both declared as `ActionResult`), seems that you can't cancel HTTP request from another method request if the first request is already started.

Comment: @praga2050 please see HTML part in the top of question i'm edit it.

Comment: Thank you very much every body.If not, is there another way? please provide me.

Comment: @user2955394 *"Calculate something that take long time".* Does this involve a table update at the end of long calculation? or multiple updates before and in between? You need to give the psuedo code of what kind of calculation or process you're talking about

Comment: @user2955394 Can you explain the process *that take long time*? If it's really slow, you can perform memory usage optimization (reduce loads, dispose unused objects ASAP, etc).

Comment: "the process that take long time?" is read/write file and insert, up date, delete data in database and calculate some value. it's not to long very much

Comment: but i want the user can cancel the process if they want

Comment: I can find solution in it's in my Edit 2.please see. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

(Now, I'm not sure if a Session value remains same through out an Http request or gets updated)

This depends on what kind of process you're running. It won't stop any running processes but it can undo and stop the further processing.

In your javascript create a variable called `processTimeStamp`. Notice, it's declaration must be outside both of these functions. Just before calling the process data, assign the `processTimeStamp` and this will be the parameter to both `ProcessData` and `CancelProcessData` methods. Since, the variable is in global scope, the same value will be sent to both of these methods.

```
<script>
    var processTimeStamp;
    function ProcessData() {
        var actionUrl = '@Url.Action("ProcessData", "Home")';
        processTimeStamp = new Date().getTime().toString();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: actionUrl,
            data: {
              processTimeStamp: processTimeStamp 
            },
            contentType: "application/Json",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.IsComplete) {
                    var reUrl = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
                    window.location = reUrl;
                } else if (result.IsCancelComplete) {
                     alert("process was cancelled");
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    }

    function CancelProcessData() {
        var actionUrl = '@Url.Action("CancelProcessData", "Home")';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: actionUrl,
            data: {
              processTimeStamp: processTimeStamp 
            },
            contentType: "application/Json",
            success: function (result) {
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Controller**:

In your `CancelProcessData` method, assign the value of `processTimeStamp` to `Session["CancelProcessTimestamp"]`. You simply can't know whether the process is cancelled or not from here.

In your `ProcessData` method, check if the `processTimeStamp` passed, is same as the `Session["CancelProcessTimestamp"]` before every process. I mean you don't have any option. (Kind of like how you'd handle `CancellationToken` in the Task Parallel Library)

```
public ActionResult ProcessData(string processTimeStamp)
{
    bool isComplete = false;
    bool isCancelComplete = false;
    string errMessage = "";

    try
    {

        // process 1 <-- this starts immediately. So you can't stop that.

        if( Convert.ToString(Session["CancelProcessTimestamp"]) != processTimeStamp)
        {
           // process 2
        }
        else
        {
           isCancelComplete = true;
        }

        // OTHER PROCESSES

        if(Convert.ToString(Session["CancelProcessTimestamp"]) != processTimeStamp)
        {
           // update to database
           isComplete = true; // only if it completes the last process
        }
        else
        {
           // you can undo the work done in process 1, 2 etc. 
           // Like deleting an uploaded file. Or if any primary key is returned from Process 1, then delete the corresponding entry in Data base
           isCancelComplete = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        errMessage = e.Message;
    }

    return Json(new { IsComplete = isComplete, IsCancelComplete = isCancelComplete , ErrorMessage = errMessage });
}


public ActionResult CancelProcessData(string processTimeStamp)
{
    Session["CancelProcessTimestamp"] = processTimeStamp;
    return Json(true);
}
```

Comment: I can find solution in it's in my Edit 2.please see. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user2955394 Does it work? in your edit, where is the process?

Comment: please see in my question in Edit2 i test process with long for loop. when click process button the request call to method ProcessData and running for long time. but when click cancel button it's call abort(). When ajax call abort() the HttpContext.Response.ClientDisconnectedToken.IsCancellationRequested is set to true then i break the loop. It's work for me.